# Client Server program in Java::server not reading text from a file line by line

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to transfer an `audio file` from server to client and write it an another file. The `server` is reading the file from the client but it is reading the contents of the file continuously ignoring the new line. For example there is a text like  "I am doing client server program" and in the next line of the file  text is "in Java". The server reading as "I am doing client server programing `Java`".
My question is how to read the contents line by line..

My code is as follows...

*

> Server

```
**try
{
`   try
        {
            System.out.println("Im server waiting for client request");
            ss=new ServerSocket(2005);
            Socket s=ss.accept();

             InputStream is = s.getInputStream( );//Input Stream
             BufferedReader fileRead =new BufferedReader(new       InputStreamReader(is));
             String fname = fileRead.readLine( );


            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream( );//socket output stream
             PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);

             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname) );//read File

             String str;//initiating string and StringBuffer

             StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            while((str = br.readLine()) !=  null) // reading line-by-line from file
            {
                sb.append(str);//append to stringBuffer sb

            }
            System.out.println("The string is in server" +sb);

            pw.println(sb);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            is.close();
            fileRead.close();
        os.close();
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.getMessage();
            e.getStackTrace();
            e.getSuppressed();
        }`
The Client side::

    try {
            System.out.println("Im client ..sending request");
            Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1",2005);//Initiate Socket

            System.out.println("Enter filename");


            BufferedReader bw=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));//Take fileName from keyBoard

            String filename=bw.readLine();//Read filename into  a string

            OutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());//output Stream
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(dout,true);

            pw.println(filename);//write filename to socket

            InputStream is = s.getInputStream( );//Input Stream
            BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String clstr;
            StringBuilder sd=new StringBuilder();
            while((clstr=in.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sd.append(clstr);
             //clstr=in.readLine();//Read String From socket into "clstr" string

            }
             System.out.println("The string in client is" +sd);

            File f=new File("A://music/kin.txt");//Open a file

            if(!f.exists())
                f.createNewFile();//if not existed create it

            try
            {
            //PrintWriter bf=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f)); //Write to a file
                BufferedWriter bf=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
            //bf.append(clstr);
            //bf.write(sd);
            bf.append(sd);
            bf.flush();
            bf.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.getMessage();
                e.getSuppressed();
                e.getStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("The Content written is" +sd);

            bw.close();
            pw.close();
        dout.close();
        in.close();
        is.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: New line in an audio file?

Comment: Please edit your code's indentation and remove some of the large numbers of consecutive blank lines. The easier you make it for people to read your code, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your description is far from clear, but I suspect this is the problem:

```
while((str = br.readLine()) !=  null) // reading line-by-line from file
{
    sb.append(str);//append to stringBuffer sb
}
```

The return value from `readLine()` *doesn't* contain a line break... and you're not adding one into your `StringBuilder`. So if you receive lines of:

- "first"
- "second"
- "third"

the result will just be "firstsecondthird". You just need to add an appropriate line break yourself:

```
// Or whatever line break you want
String lineBreak = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while((str = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(str);
    sb.append(lineBreak);
}
```

Note that if you really *are* trying to transfer audio files like this, you shouldn't - audio files are *binary* data, so you should just read from an `InputStream`; don't use a `Reader` at all, as that's designed for *text* data.

Comment: Thanks for your precious answer.I am transferring a text file currently.

Comment: @user88368: So why even say that you're transferring an audio file? Bear in mind that if you structure your code to just transfer any binary data, that will *also* handle text files...